# Does having CWM mean bootloader is unlocked?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, bootloader, sim-unlocking

I flashed CWM using Rom Manager. Does this mean that my Galaxy S4 bootloader is unlocked?

I'm using Samsung Galaxy S4 (SGH-I337M) (Canadian Telus)

Answer (score 2):

Not *per se*. You can flash any recovery you like without unlocking the bootloader, but you need to unlock it to boot the recovery. If you flashed CWM **and you can boot it**, it shows that the bootloader is unlocked.

Comment: what do you mean that I can boot it?  I press power volume down and home button and go to cwm recovery(the black page) then I can do Nandroid backup and restore factory reset ...  so I guess it means that I have booted into cwm right?

Comment: its weird because I didn't try to unlock bootloader I used odin and CF-Auto-Root-jfltecan-jfltevl-sghi337m to root my phone. it didn't ask me if I want to unlock it or not.

Comment: Your first comment is exactly what Dan meant: booting into recovery brings you to CWM – so yes, your bootloader seems to be unlocked.