# Bootloader unlocked

Tags: rooting, root-access, samsung-galaxy-s-4, bootloader-lock

Rooted samsung galaxy s4 using odin& CF Auto root. Then flashed CWM using rom manager. Now I can go to CWM  recovery mode (using power+volume up+ home) . I can get NAndroid backup. Does this mean that I have unlocked my bootloader?
After a lot of googling I think I should use ADB 'fast root in order to unlock bootloader. but since I'm already booting cwm in recovery mode others say I'm alreay unlocked!!!
 the method I used from http://autoroot.chainfire.eu/ isn't for unlocking its for rooting. please explain Thanks.
actually now that I read  the instruction in chainfire website don't understand why rooting worked for me he has a warning that using those auto root files on a locked bootloader will brick the phone!!!

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! If you want to add details to your question, please don't do so via comments; you can always [edit] your question ;) Apart from that: Was that you asking the same question yesterday? [CWM installed does it mean bootloader is unlocked?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/81540/16575)

Comment: Lost that account.had registered it with an email that doesn't exist:(

Comment: No reason to re-post as duplicate. You can always [contact staff](http://android.stackexchange.com/contact) asking to have that account "merged" into your current one. If you can provide them the registration details (to prove it's yours), they usually do.

Comment: @Izzy can you read the question again please? I have changed it

Comment: I can't help you with that, Sam. But I strongly suggest to contact staff to get your accounts merged, to avoid duplication you could update your original question then. Might cause some confusion otherwise, with details spread across multiple locations ;)

Comment: @izzy done that already.hopefully they will do that soon

Comment: Shouldn't take too long, give it a few days at max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily, just because you rooted your android device doesn't mean that you unlock the bootloader. You must understand that is very different root from unlock bootloader and they have different uses too.
**Root** your phone means that now you have the sudo permission(admin permission) and you are able to manage your android as you want. Remove stock apps, edit the system files (that is dangerous if you doesn't know what you're doing!) and lot of new possibilities.
**boot unlock** your phone means that you can install a custom recovery boot, like the most knows: ClockWorkMod (CWM) and TeamWin Recovery Project. And also be able to install a custom ROM like CyanogenMod, Paranoid, or other Android Open Source Project (AOSP) ROM.

As different devices have diferent methods to unlock the boot, it should search on google with your exact model and how to unlock it. But most devices uses fastboot as the unlock method (Sony, Nexus - Samsung not, I used odin too).

Yes, it can brick you phone if you don't make it right. The tool CF-Auto-Root explicit alerts:

> UNLOCK BOOTLOADERS If you have locked bootloaders, flashing one of
>   these will probably brick your device - with the exception of Nexus
>   devices, which will usually automatically "OEM unlock" and wipe your
>   data !

How to check if your device is rooted: 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joeykrim.rootcheck

How to check if your device is boot unlocked:
Please check search on google for tutorials, because change for each brand and model. But note that it is more an advance feature than a simple root and easily could get you phone wicked if somethings went wrong.

This site might help you, it for Samsung galaxy s4:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2551401

Comment: "boot unlock your phone means that know you can install a custom recovery boot, like the most knows: ClockWorkMod (CWM) and TeamWin Recovery Project"  I'm using CWM so I should be boot unlocked right? I did alot of googling to confirm that I have boot loader unlocked but didn't get the answer (using Samsung Galaxy S4 SGH-I337M)

Comment: @Sam Sorry, but so I didn't get so what are you asking for. I read again, but It is the same I has thought you asked...

Comment: ok I understand that rooting isn't same as bootloader unlocking.   I want to know that if I installed CWM with rom manager successfully does it mean that I am already boot unlocked?

Comment: I didn't find any method to check bootloader for my device no one said how I can confirm if it is unlocked or not.

Comment: I think you should not be able to unlock automatically, as the site warn you to be careful. And I explained in the answer that to unlock the bootloader you should search on google for methods for your device as it change for each model.

Comment: @Sam I added an link to a page with a discussion about how to install bootloader on a samsung s4. Take a look and see if helps

Comment: I see well the link isn't for sgh-i337m but I guess that as close I can get to unlocking my phone. (Not feeli g safe to try it since no one with my model mentioned it) thx though